# Large space between Feynman loop diagram in tikz picture and the caption

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, tikz-feynman

I'm trying to put two Feynman diagrams side-by-side, but the 3-point loop diagram will not be aligned with 4-point loop diagram correctly whatever I do!
Here is my code

```
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
\feynmandiagram [layered layout, horizontal=b to c] {
a -- [scalar, edge label = $H$] b [dot,black]
-- [fermion, half left,edge label = $f$] c [dot,black]
-- [fermion, half left,edge label = $\bar{f}$] b,
c -- [scalar,  edge label = $H$ ] d,
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0cm}
\hspace{3.4cm}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
\feynmandiagram [layered layout, horizontal=b to c] {
a -- [scalar, edge label = $H$] b [dot,blue]
-- [scalar, min distance=3cm, edge label = $\phi_i$] b 
-- [scalar,  edge label = $H$ ] c,
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{Higgs self-energy diagram}  
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to put them in the same `tikzpicture`, and use `\diagram [xshift=5cm ..` for the second one. If you want to move the second one down, add `,yshift=-1cm` after the `xshift`.

Some comments:

- `\feynmandiagram` starts its own `tikzpicture` environment, so don't use it inside a `tikzpicture`. Either use

  ```
  \feynmandiagram ...
  ```

  or use

  ```
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{feynman}
  \diagram ...
  \end{feynman}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  ```
- Having `\begin{center} .. \end{center}` *outside* a `figure` environment is actually rather unhelpful. It doesn't center the figure, it adds additional vertical space, and with any other float specifier than `H` the figure will likely float outside it. Instead, put `\centering` right after `\begin{figure}`
- Using `\captionof{figure}{..}` isn't necessary when you are inside a `figure` environment, then `\caption{..}` is enough.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
\diagram [layered layout, horizontal=b to c] {
a -- [scalar, edge label = $H$] b [dot,black]
-- [fermion, half left,edge label = $f$] c [dot,black]
-- [fermion, half left,edge label = $\bar{f}$] b,
c -- [scalar,  edge label = $H$ ] d,
};

\diagram [xshift=5cm,layered layout, horizontal=b to c] {
a -- [scalar, edge label = $H$] b [dot,blue]
-- [scalar, min distance=3cm, edge label = $\phi_i$] b 
-- [scalar,  edge label = $H$ ] c,
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Higgs self-energy diagram}  
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

## Separate captions

To get separate captions, use two `\feynmandiagram`s. For subcaptions, load the `subcaption` package and place each `\feynmandiagram` in a `subfigure` environment as in the example below.

If you don't want subcaptions, use basically exactly the same syntax, but replace `subfigure` with `minipage`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\feynmandiagram [layered layout, horizontal=b to c] {
a -- [scalar, edge label = $H$] b [dot,black]
-- [fermion, half left,edge label = $f$] c [dot,black]
-- [fermion, half left,edge label = $\bar{f}$] b,
c -- [scalar,  edge label = $H$ ] d,
};
\caption{Something}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering

\feynmandiagram [layered layout, horizontal=b to c] {
a -- [scalar, edge label = $H$] b [dot,blue]
-- [scalar, min distance=3cm, edge label = $\phi_i$] b 
-- [scalar,  edge label = $H$ ] c,
};
\caption{Something else}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Higgs self-energy diagram}  
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\feynmandiagram [layered layout, horizontal=b to c] {
a -- [scalar, edge label = $H$] b [dot,black]
-- [fermion, half left,edge label = $f$] c [dot,black]
-- [fermion, half left,edge label = $\bar{f}$] b,
c -- [scalar,  edge label = $H$ ] d,
};
\caption{Something}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering

\feynmandiagram [layered layout, horizontal=b to c] {
a -- [scalar, edge label = $H$] b [dot,blue]
-- [scalar, min distance=3cm, edge label = $\phi_i$] b 
-- [scalar,  edge label = $H$ ] c,
};
\caption{Something else}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Torbjørn T. for your answer and explanation. I appreciate it. I was also wondering if there is anyway to put caption for each diagrams!

Comment: @JoydeepRoy Subcaptions (Fig 1a and 1b) or not (Fig 1 and 2)?

Comment: @JoydeepRoy Answer updated.

Comment: T Thanks a ton for your help. I really appreciate it.